# add price of each item to customer transaction email

Tags: magento-1.8, email, transaction

Thank you in advance for any help!

I am wondering how to show the price of each item in the customer thank you for your order email.
Right now it displays like this 
Item name then the sku number then the qty then the subtotal

Using the variable 
{{layout area="frontend" handle="sales_email_order_invoice_items" invoice=$invoice order=$order}}

I need to display individual price of each item not just sub total of the entire order.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Check the sales.xml inside the layout folder.

```
<sales_email_order_invoice_items>
    <block type="sales/order_email_invoice_items" name="items" template="email/order/invoice/items.phtml">
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>default</type><block>sales/order_email_items_default</block><template>email/order/items/invoice/default.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>sales/order_email_items_order_grouped</block><template>email/order/items/invoice/default.phtml</template></action>
        <block type="sales/order_invoice_totals" name="invoice_totals" template="sales/order/totals.phtml">
            <action method="setLabelProperties"><value>colspan="3" align="right" style="padding:3px 9px"</value></action>
            <action method="setValueProperties"><value>align="right" style="padding:3px 9px"</value></action>
            <block type="tax/sales_order_tax" name="tax" template="tax/order/tax.phtml">
                <action method="setIsPlaneMode"><value>1</value></action>
            </block>
        </block>
    </block>
    <block type="core/text_list" name="additional.product.info" />
</sales_email_order_invoice_items>
```

There you will see the PHTML being used for default and grouped products, you can change what you need in there.

In app/design/frontend/base/default/template/email/order/invoice/items.phtml you will have to add an extra column and then in app/design/frontend/base/default/template/email/order/items/order/default.phtml you can set the value for the column you just created.

Comment: Please mark it as accepted if the question is resolved.